# Как закрепить FAB к нижней границе диалогового окна?

Tags: android, material-design, android-dialog

Хочу закрепить `FAB` на нижней границе окошка. Тоесть, чтобы одна половинка была в окне, а другая на затемнении. Сейчас разметка окошка выглядит так

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:weightSum="100"
android:id="@+id/alert_root"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <widget.CircleImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alert_photo"
        android:src="@drawable/image_1"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_weight="75"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="#000000">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Имя"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/alert_family"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_family"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Фамилия"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/alert_verbose"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_verbose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Описание"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/done"

    app:backgroundTint="#F28A14"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/alert_root"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде `anchor` правильно использую. Но что-то не так...

Comment: Зачем вы используете CoordinatorLayout, у вас вроде нет динамических виджетов (выдвигающихся частей каких-то). Не думаю, что кнопку можно будет вывести за границы корневого контейнера (рамки диалогового окна)

Comment: Я использую `anchor`. Он работает с `CoordinatorLayout`. Можно. Видел окно, в котором `FAB` также торчал наполовину.

Comment: Используйте отрицательные маргины или составьте разметку так, чтобы FAB вылезал за пределы диалога добавив диалог и FAB в ещё один контейнер

Comment: Спасибо но уже передумал.

Comment: Подожду пока будет более нормальный туториал. Якорь этот ещё не додуман